# Integral of $h(t)$ is $9/5t$

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> The slope of a tangent line to a graph of a function $h(t)$ is $9/5t$. The function passes through the point $(3,3)$. Find $h(8)$.

It seems simple but I can't seem to get the right answer to this.

I'm just looking for the steps to solving this. I get the integral, determine my constant using the point given, and then solve for $t=8$?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it $h(t) = \dfrac 9{5t}$, or $h(t) = \dfrac 95 t$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know $h'(t) = 9t/5$. Find
$$h(t) = \int h'(t) + C$$
and use the fact that $h(3)=3$ to determine $C$.

Then find $h(8)$ by plugging in.

**EDIT** Let's try together.

$$h(t) = C+ \int h'(t)dt = C + \int \frac{9tdt}{5} = C + \frac{9t^2}{2\cdot 5} = 9t^2/10 + C$$
and we know that
$$3 = h(3)= 9\cdot 3^2/10 + C = 8.1+C$$
which implies $C = -5.1$ and so $h(8) = 9 \cdot 8^2/10-5.1 = 52.5$

Could it be that you had $h'(t) = \frac{9}{5t}$ instead, in which case
$$
h(t) = C + \int \frac{9dt}{5t} = \frac{9\ln t}{5} + C
$$
so
$$3 = h(3) = \frac{9\ln 3}{5} + C$$
and then
$$
h(8) = \frac{9\ln 8}{5} + 3 - \frac{9\ln 3}{5} = 3 + \frac{9\ln (8/3)}{5}
     \approx 4.7654
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I still cant get the solution.
I get the integral as 9/(5t/2)+c.

h(3) = 1.2+c

1.8=c

h(8)=9/(5(8)/2)+1.8

And I'm way off of the answer which is given as 4.76

Comment: @user3376379 edited

Comment: Incredible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems from your comment that your function is $$h'(t) = \dfrac 9{5t} = \dfrac 95\cdot \frac 1t$$

So we need to find $$h(t)=\int \frac 95 \cdot \frac 1t \,dt = \frac 95\int \frac 1t\,dt$$

---

Hint: What is derivative of $\,\ln(t)\;?\;\;$ Recall $$\dfrac{d}{dt}\Big(\ln(t)\Big) = \dfrac 1t$$